# WiFi Driver Freezes

Tags: wifi, drivers

I installed [this WiFi driver](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E), as I have Mediatek MT7630E.  It connects and works pretty well, but whenever it disconnects my computer freezes.

So I tried blacklisting some drivers:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and added

```
blacklist eth0
blacklist eth0_cs
```

But it still freezes.

---

**Details**

I got eth0 from running this command:

```
$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

wlan0 seems to be the one that connects when my WiFi is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

`eth0` is your ethernet port. It shouldn't have any bearing on the WiFi driver.

The driver you have installed is a modified version of [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315002024/http://mediatek.com/en/downloads/mt7630-pcie/) official driver. That page mentions the driver only supports kernels 3.13 & 3.14, though elementary is shipped with newer kernels.

While the *'modifications and fixes'* may make it work on later kernel versions, I'd imagine you will have more luck posting a bug report on the github bug tracker where you obtained the driver.

It's worth noting that there appears to be several forks of this driver. I suggest reading through this [thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146) as it contains contributions from the author of your modified version and several others. You may find one of the other forks works better for you. Note the very last post on that thread is by someone with your issue.

Comment: Would I be able to just buy a WiFi stick or microSD card instead? Like this: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00DR590OM/ref=cm_sw_r_em_awd_JlpgwbACAB10F